# Tridion Component Link Not Resolving

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am using SDL Tridion 2011. I have created a Component  of field type 'text', and linked an already published component to a text in it.

After this i have inserted the component to a page and published that (i used Link Resolver TBB). when i viewed that page in browser,link was not appearing and when i checked code , following was wriiten in place of link

```
<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:150-12575-64" 
    ComponentURI="tcm:150-12344" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false"
    LinkText="component" LinkAttributes=" title=&#34;Video link&#34; 
    target=&#34;_blank&#34; " TextOnFail="true"/>
```

Template type is Compound Template and Code :-

```
<CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:150-12576-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Test" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:b81e2790-ded1-4fb2-b09a-4a2975c2938e" />
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:150-12176-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Default Finish Actions" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:a13c5753-adfc-4e93-912f-ee3d93b6a828" />
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
</CompoundTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you please share the piece of code from Component template for displaying the component details?

Comment: @HustonLopes: I have included Component template code above

Comment: Are you sure linking is working else where in the site and the page using component(tcm:150-12344) is actually published?

Comment: @vikaskumar:- yes i am sure, the page using component(tcm:150-12344) is published

Comment: And is linking working at all, for other components/pages?

Comment: Also try show where used on components(tcm:150-12344) and see if page comes on using list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Link Resolver TBB will resolve a Component link to either a ASP.NET or JSP tag depending on the configuration of your Deployer and/or Publication Target. Looking at your tag it is resolved to a ASP.NET tag (judging from the `runat="server"` attribute).

Now to make it work you must ensure you configure the API server role for your ASP.NET web application and of course your pages need to have the right file extension (.aspx usually) to ensure the tags in them are executed.

Simply put what you need to do is register the tag prefix for the SDL Tridion Dynamic Link tag. You do this in your wep applications `web.config` file, as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="tridion" 
                     namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI"
                     assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

More about this topic can be found in our online documentation: [Configuring the API server role for a .NET Web application](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_FF19F86A63E246F793D64495849EDEDF) (logon required, see [here](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion) for details)